# Android appUI updating slow

Tags: android, database, android-asynctask, ui-thread

In my app when a button clicked, the database is updated first, then that data is sent to the server. Before sending data that data is encrypted. The update to the db is done in one async task and the encryption and sending data is done through another async task like the below

1) update db

```
 private class UpdateThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private MessageThread messageThread;

    private UpdateThread(MessageThread thread) {
        this.messageThread = thread;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        action.update(messageThread);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        PollReply pollReply = new PollReply(messageThread);
        pollReply.execute();
    }
}
```

2) encrypt data and send to server

```
private class PollReply extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private MessageThread messageThread;

    private PollReply(MessageThread thread) {
        this.messageThread = thread;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        messageThread.setHashcode(HashUtility.encryptString(messageThread.getRandomcode() + messageThread.getUserId()));
        messageThread.setStrippedHashCode(StringUtility.reduceToBytes(messageThread.getHashcode(), 16));
        try {
            messageThread.setAnswerEnc(EncryptionUtility.encrypt(messageThread.getAnswer(), messageThread.getStrippedHashCode()));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        PollReplyAsyncTask asyncTask = new PollReplyAsyncTask(activity, false, messageThread, messageThread.getUserId());
        asyncTask.execute();
    }
}
```

and these async tasks are called like below

```
UpdateThread updateThread = new UpdateThread(message);
updateThread.execute();

PollReply pollReply = new PollReply(message);
pollReply.execute();
```

When I comment the second async task, the db is updated immediately and UI is updated immediately too.
But when I use the second async task, the db is updated but the ui is updated after the execution of second async task executed. I think UI thread is blocked somewhere. Any solution to this problem?

```
if (message.getOptionsCount() > 0) {

                    if (message.getOptionsCount() > 1) {
                        pollChoice1.setText(message.getOption1());
                        pollChoice2.setText(message.getOption2());

                        backgroundWidth = 0;
                        if (message.getOptionsCount() == 2) {
                            pollChoice1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            pollChoice2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            pollChoice3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            pollChoice4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            pollChoice5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            if ((message.getVisibility().equals("public") && message.getAnswered()) || (message.getType() == MessageThread.OUT_MESSAGE)) {
                                pollChoice3Background.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                pollChoice4Background.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                pollChoice5Background.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                if (responseCount > 0) {
                                    pollChoice1Background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice2Background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    float widthFloat = (float) (option1Count * 100.0 / responseCount);
                                    backgroundWidth = (int) widthFloat;
                                    int total_width = pollChoice1.getMeasuredWidth();
                                    pollChoice1Background.setText("" + backgroundWidth + "%");
                                    backgroundWidth = (total_width * backgroundWidth / 100);
                                    pollChoice1Background.getLayoutParams().width = backgroundWidth;

                                    widthFloat = (float) (option2Count * 100.0 / responseCount);
                                    backgroundWidth = (int) widthFloat;
                                    total_width = pollChoice1.getMeasuredWidth();
                                    pollChoice2Background.setText("" + backgroundWidth + "%");
                                    backgroundWidth = (total_width * backgroundWidth / 100);
                                    pollChoice2Background.getLayoutParams().width = backgroundWidth;
                                } else {
                                    pollChoice1Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice2Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                            } else {
                                pollChoice1Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                pollChoice2Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }

                            line1choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            line2choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            line3choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            choice1Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            choice2Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            choice3Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            choice4Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            choice5Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            choice6Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        } else if (message.getOptionsCount() == 3) {

                            dps = 150;
                            pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
                            feed.getLayoutParams().height = pixels;

                            pollChoice1.setText(message.getOption1());
                            pollChoice2.setText(message.getOption2());
                            pollChoice3.setText(message.getOption3());

                            pollChoice1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            pollChoice2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            pollChoice3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            pollChoice4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            pollChoice5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            if ((message.getVisibility().equals("public") && message.getAnswered()) || (message.getType() == MessageThread.OUT_MESSAGE)) {
                                pollChoice4Background.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                pollChoice5Background.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                if (responseCount > 0) {
                                    pollChoice1Background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice2Background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice3Background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                                    float width_float = (float) (option1Count * 100.0 / responseCount);
                                    backgroundWidth = (int) width_float;
                                    int total_width = pollChoice1.getMeasuredWidth();
                                    pollChoice1Background.setText("" + backgroundWidth + "%");
                                    backgroundWidth = (total_width * backgroundWidth / 100);
                                    pollChoice1Background.getLayoutParams().width = backgroundWidth;

                                    width_float = (float) (option2Count * 100.0 / responseCount);
                                    backgroundWidth = (int) width_float;
                                    total_width = pollChoice2.getMeasuredWidth();
                                    pollChoice2Background.setText("" + backgroundWidth + "%");
                                    backgroundWidth = (total_width * backgroundWidth / 100);
                                    pollChoice2Background.getLayoutParams().width = backgroundWidth;

                                    width_float = (float) (option3Count * 100.0 / responseCount);
                                    backgroundWidth = (int) width_float;
                                    total_width = pollChoice3.getMeasuredWidth();
                                    pollChoice3Background.setText("" + backgroundWidth + "%");
                                    backgroundWidth = (total_width * backgroundWidth / 100);
                                    pollChoice3Background.getLayoutParams().width = backgroundWidth;
                                } else {
                                    pollChoice1Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice2Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice3Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                            } else {
                                pollChoice1Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                pollChoice2Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                pollChoice3Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }

                            line1choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            line2choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            line3choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            line4choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            choice1Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            choice2Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            choice3Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            choice4Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            choice5Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            choice6Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else if (message.getOptionsCount() == 4) {

                            dps = 100;
                            pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
                            feed.getLayoutParams().height = pixels;

                            pollChoice1.setText(message.getOption1());
                            pollChoice2.setText(message.getOption2());
                            pollChoice3.setText(message.getOption3());
                            pollChoice4.setText(message.getOption4());

                            pollChoice1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            pollChoice2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            pollChoice3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            pollChoice4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            pollChoice5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            if ((message.getVisibility().equals("public") && message.getAnswered()) || (message.getType() == MessageThread.OUT_MESSAGE)) {
                                pollChoice5Background.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                if (responseCount > 0) {
                                    pollChoice1Background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice2Background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice3Background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice4Background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    float width_float = (float) (option1Count * 100.0 / responseCount);
                                    backgroundWidth = (int) width_float;
                                    int total_width = pollChoice1.getMeasuredWidth();
                                    pollChoice1Background.setText("" + backgroundWidth + "%");
                                    backgroundWidth = (total_width * backgroundWidth / 100);
                                    pollChoice1Background.getLayoutParams().width = backgroundWidth;

                                    width_float = (float) (option2Count * 100.0 / responseCount);
                                    backgroundWidth = (int) width_float;
                                    total_width = pollChoice2.getMeasuredWidth();
                                    pollChoice2Background.setText("" + backgroundWidth + "%");
                                    backgroundWidth = (total_width * backgroundWidth / 100);
                                    pollChoice2Background.getLayoutParams().width = backgroundWidth;

                                    width_float = (float) (option3Count * 100.0 / responseCount);
                                    backgroundWidth = (int) width_float;
                                    total_width = pollChoice3.getMeasuredWidth();
                                    pollChoice3Background.setText("" + backgroundWidth + "%");
                                    backgroundWidth = (total_width * backgroundWidth / 100);
                                    pollChoice3Background.getLayoutParams().width = backgroundWidth;

                                    width_float = (float) (option4Count * 100.0 / responseCount);
                                    backgroundWidth = (int) width_float;
                                    total_width = pollChoice4.getMeasuredWidth();
                                    pollChoice4Background.setText("" + backgroundWidth + "%");
                                    backgroundWidth = (total_width * backgroundWidth / 100);
                                    pollChoice4Background.getLayoutParams().width = backgroundWidth;
                                } else {
                                    pollChoice1Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice2Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice3Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice4Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                            } else {
                                pollChoice1Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                pollChoice2Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                pollChoice3Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                pollChoice4Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }

                            line1choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            line2choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            line3choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            line4choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            line5choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            choice1Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            choice2Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            choice3Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            choice4Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            choice5Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            choice6Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else if (message.getOptionsCount() == 5) {

                            dps = 100;
                            pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
                            feed.getLayoutParams().height = pixels;

                            pollChoice1.setText(message.getOption1());
                            pollChoice2.setText(message.getOption2());
                            pollChoice3.setText(message.getOption3());
                            pollChoice4.setText(message.getOption4());
                            pollChoice5.setText(message.getOption5());

                            pollChoice1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            pollChoice2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            pollChoice3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            pollChoice4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            pollChoice5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            if ((message.getVisibility().equals("public") && message.getAnswered()) || (message.getType() == MessageThread.OUT_MESSAGE)) {
                                if (responseCount > 0) {
                                    pollChoice1Background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice2Background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice3Background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice4Background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice5Background.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    float width_float = (float) (option1Count * 100.0 / responseCount);
                                    backgroundWidth = (int) width_float;
                                    int total_width = pollChoice1.getMeasuredWidth();
                                    pollChoice1Background.setText("" + backgroundWidth + "%");
                                    backgroundWidth = (total_width * backgroundWidth / 100);
                                    pollChoice1Background.getLayoutParams().width = backgroundWidth;

                                    width_float = (float) (option2Count * 100.0 / responseCount);
                                    backgroundWidth = (int) width_float;
                                    total_width = pollChoice2.getMeasuredWidth();
                                    pollChoice2Background.setText("" + backgroundWidth + "%");
                                    backgroundWidth = (total_width * backgroundWidth / 100);
                                    pollChoice2Background.getLayoutParams().width = backgroundWidth;

                                    width_float = (float) (option3Count * 100.0 / responseCount);
                                    backgroundWidth = (int) width_float;
                                    total_width = pollChoice3.getMeasuredWidth();
                                    pollChoice3Background.setText("" + backgroundWidth + "%");
                                    backgroundWidth = (total_width * backgroundWidth / 100);
                                    pollChoice3Background.getLayoutParams().width = backgroundWidth;

                                    width_float = (float) (option4Count * 100.0 / responseCount);
                                    backgroundWidth = (int) width_float;
                                    total_width = pollChoice4.getMeasuredWidth();
                                    pollChoice4Background.setText("" + backgroundWidth + "%");
                                    backgroundWidth = (total_width * backgroundWidth / 100);
                                    pollChoice4Background.getLayoutParams().width = backgroundWidth;

                                    width_float = (float) (option5Count * 100.0 / responseCount);
                                    backgroundWidth = (int) width_float;
                                    total_width = pollChoice5.getMeasuredWidth();
                                    pollChoice5Background.setText("" + backgroundWidth + "%");
                                    backgroundWidth = (total_width * backgroundWidth / 100);
                                    pollChoice5Background.getLayoutParams().width = backgroundWidth;

                                } else {
                                    pollChoice1Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice2Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice3Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice4Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    pollChoice5Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                            } else {
                                pollChoice1Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                pollChoice2Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                pollChoice3Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                pollChoice4Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                pollChoice5Background.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }

                            line1choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            line2choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            line3choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            line4choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            line5choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            line6choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            choice1Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            choice2Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            choice3Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            choice4Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            choice5Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            choice6Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

the above code is where i  update the Ui. Here db gets updated immediately. But the Ui is not updated accordingly. I update the Ui in bindView() of the custom adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create and execute the AsyncTask from the UI thread. You created it on the AsyncTask's doInBackground() which works on a non UI Thread. Change it to

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      PollReplyAsyncTask asyncTask = new PollReplyAsyncTask(activity, false, messageThread, messageThread.getUserId());
      asyncTask.execute();
   }
}
```

**Why?**

From the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html under Threading Rules

> - The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done    automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.
> - **The task instance must be created on the UI thread.**
> - **execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.**
> - Do not call onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result),    doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...) manually.
> - The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a    second execution is attempted.)

Comment: here the problem is that the ui updates after the second async task executes.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: in the first async task I update database, and I want to immediately show the result in UI. But the result got updated after the second async task executed

Comment: added some code to where i exactly update the ui. Not the whole code. because there is lot of code

Comment: removed the calling of pollreplyasyctask and now its working fine. why is it blocking the ui

Comment: got solution by running the PollReplyAsyncTask in ruOnUiThread. and thanks

Answer (score 0):

A little more details would have been better.

1. If your second async task has a lot of things to do, and you are updating the UI in onPostExecute() method, then obviously the UI will not be updated until the task is completed.
2. You are executing another async task within the second async task. That may also be the problem if you are doing any long operations in that.

So, the solution would be you could show a progress bar while the data is being encrypted and updated, or you can Update the UI first and then encrypt and upload the data.